# Is it possible to get a master's in speech language pathology online or part-time?

Tags: masters, online-learning, part-time

I am currently looking into a possible career change as a speech language pathologist. Is it possible to get a masters in SLP online? Or are there any part time programs that would allow me time for work?

Answer (score 2):

There's at least one program at the [University of Wisconsin in Eau Claire](http://www.uwec.edu/CSD/grad/online-graduate-program-in-speech-language-pathology.htm). It's designed as a part-time, online master's. You're required to attend 3 one-week sessions on-campus each summer over three years.

If you don't have an undergraduate degree in communication sciences and disorders, there are [30-40 credit hours of required courses - PDF](http://www.uwec.edu/CSD/grad/upload/Postbacc-courses_OLGP.pdf) before you can start the master's.